# RedShift NaNs in UNION EXCEPT INTERSECT queries

Tags: sql, nan, amazon-redshift

I'm running two equivalent queries in RedShift, and I'm getting two different results:

```
SELECT  'NaN'::double precision as nan
intersect
SELECT  'NaN'::double precision as nan;
```

1 record returned: NaN

```
SELECT  'NaN'::double precision as nan
into    #temp;

select  *
FROM    #temp
intersect
select  *
FROM    #temp
```

zero records returned

Does anyone understand why RedShift is treating NaNs different when it's returned from a table rather than just an inline SELECT statement?

Comment: what happens when you specify the column name in the select instead of *?

Comment: Both return 1 row in the most recent version of Postgres on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ee6d/3).

Comment: can you do a select * from #temp BEFORE doing the intersect to make sure you have the data as expected in the table

Comment: @I.K. doing a select * from #temp before returns 1 record, NaN.  If I change the INTERSECT to a UNION, it returns two records. nan, nan.  The interesting thing is that it returns nan, not NaN.  Not sure if that means anything, but may point to something redshift is doing that's weird.

Comment: @I.K. specifying the column name returns the same result, no records.

Comment: Unsupported features in Redshift did this to me (generate_series). In inline SELECT generate_series work flawlessly, but every time it touched redshift table it produced weird results. (Just my 2 cents...)

Comment: Not sure about intersect, but UNION and UNION ALL behave differently as you may know. May be intersect is like UNION which avoids full row duplicates.